# Achieve a centered node with equal edge lengths using tkz-graph

Tags: tkz-graph

I use `tkz-graph` to produce the following graph:

[image]

The code to produce the graph is as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
        \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
        \SetVertexMath
        \Vertex{w_0}
        \SO(w_0){w_1}
        \EA(w_0){w_2}
        \EA(w_1){w_3}
        \SOEA[unit=0.75](w_2){w_4}
        
        \Edge(w_0)(w_2)
        \Edge(w_1)(w_3)
        \Edge(w_2)(w_4)
        \Edge(w_3)(w_4)
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the only documentation I could find is in French, a language I do not know. With some tinkering, I was able to get w4 centred between w2 and w3 (at least I think I did). What I can't figure out how to do is adjust the length of the edges that connect to w4 so that they're the same length as the other two edges.

How do I make all the edges in this graph the same length?

**Update**: while Torbjørn T.'s answer is great, I'd ideally like a more automatic solution that doesn't require manual calculation. Something that would, e.g., force equality of edge length between all nodes, regardless of the GraphUnit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if there is a simpler way, but some calculations lead to the code below. Note that 2.12 = 1.5*sqrt(2), and 1.06 = 1.5/sqrt(2).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
        \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
        \SetVertexMath
        \Vertex{w_0}
        \SO[unit=2.12](w_0){w_1}
        \EA(w_0){w_2}
        \EA(w_1){w_3}
        \SOEA[unit=1.06](w_2){w_4}

        \Edge(w_0)(w_2)
        \Edge(w_1)(w_3)
        \Edge(w_2)(w_4)
        \Edge(w_3)(w_4)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## A different story

Another possible way would be to redefine `\SOEA` and similar commands, adding scaling by `1/sqrt(2)`. You might want to swap around the definition of the vertices in that case. For example:

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\NOEA}[1][]{\@hautdroite[#1]}%
\def\@hautdroite[#1](#2)#3{% 
\begingroup% 
  \setkeys[GR]{vertex}{#1}%
  \path [scale=1/sqrt(2)] (#2)--++(\cmdGR@vertex@unit,\cmdGR@vertex@unit) coordinate (#3); 
  \Vertex[#1,Node]{#3} 
\endgroup%
}

\renewcommand*{\NOWE}[1][]{\@hautgauche[#1]}%
\def\@hautgauche[#1](#2)#3{% 
\begingroup% 
  \setkeys[GR]{vertex}{#1}%
  \path [scale=1/sqrt(2)] (#2)--++(-\cmdGR@vertex@unit,\cmdGR@vertex@unit) coordinate (#3);
  \Vertex[#1,Node]{#3} 
\endgroup%
}

\renewcommand*{\SOEA}[1][]{\@basdroite[#1]}%
\def\@basdroite[#1](#2)#3{% 
\begingroup% 
  \setkeys[GR]{vertex}{#1}%
  \path [scale=1/sqrt(2)] (#2)--++(\cmdGR@vertex@unit,-\cmdGR@vertex@unit) coordinate (#3);
  \Vertex[#1,Node]{#3} 
\endgroup%
}

\renewcommand*{\SOWE}[1][]{\@basgauche[#1]}%
\def\@basgauche[#1](#2)#3{% 
\begingroup% 
  \setkeys[GR]{vertex}{#1}%
  \path [scale=1/sqrt(2)] (#2)--++(-\cmdGR@vertex@unit,-\cmdGR@vertex@unit) coordinate (#3);
  \Vertex[#1,Node]{#3} 
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6, every node/.style={scale=0.6}]
        \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
        \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
        \SetVertexMath
        \Vertex{w_0}
        \EA(w_0){w_2}
        \SOEA(w_2){w_4}
        \SOWE(w_4){w_3}
        \WE(w_3){w_1}

        \Edge(w_0)(w_2)
        \Edge(w_1)(w_3)
        \Edge(w_2)(w_4)
        \Edge(w_3)(w_4)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, how could I forget to use the handy old Pythagorean Theorem! That definitely does the trick, thanks! Will hold off on accepting so as to not discourage someone from posting a more automatic solution.

Comment: @Dennis I updated, see if that is useful.

Comment: Perfect! Definitely could not have come up with this on my own!

Answer (score 2):

Relatively easy task with the `chains` library which uses the `positioning` library, thus setting the `node distance` to one distance (and not two, e.g. `1cm and 1cm`) will achieve this.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\tikz[thick, start chain=going right, node distance=1cm]
  \node foreach \i/\d in {0/, 2/right, 4/below right, 3/below left, 1/left}
    [circle, draw, text depth=+0pt, on chain=going \d, join] {$w_{\i}$};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]